# How do I translate Datastore entity to BigQuery TableRow object in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I have the following DoFN function that kind of does it but there is no documentation of questions I could find about it.

- Problem No. 1 is how do I automatically translate keys so they are constructed in BigQuery in the same way that the BigQuery does it when importing form Datastore backup file?
- Problem No. 2 is how to handle timestamps? The code below breaks the pipeline with following message:

> JSON object specified for non-record field: timestamp

Here is a code I wrote:

```
public class SensorObservationEntityToRowFn extends DoFn<Entity, TableRow> {
    /**
     * In this example, put the whole string into single BigQuery field.
     */
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        Map<String, Value> props = getPropertyMap(c.element());
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        row.set("id", c.element().getKey().getPathElement(c.element().getKey().getPathElementCount()-1).getId());
        if (
                props.get("property1") != null &&
                props.get("property2") != null
                ) {
            // Map data from the source Entity to the destination TableRow
            row.set("property1", props.get("property1").getStringValue());
            row.set("property2", props.get("property2").getStringValue());
        }
        row.set("source_type", props.get("source_type").getStringValue());
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(props.get("timestamp").getTimestampMicrosecondsValue()/1000L);
        row.set("timestamp", dateTime);
        // Output new TableRow only if all data is present in the source
        c.output(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just found a resolution to the timestamp problem:

`DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(props.get("timestamp").getTimestampMicrosecondsValue()/1000L);
row.set("timestamp", ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(dateTime));`
No idea though how the timestamp should be constructed in order to avoid using unknown libraries.

Comment: If this resolves your issue, could you post it as an answer, please?

Answer (score 2):

My expectation was to find something in helper classes, but I was unsuccessful. Guess Google is still adding new bits to their APIs. Maybe in the next version.
The biggest problem is that the API is a little not intuitive and inconsistent with other parts. Entity's key should have it's own accessor method instead of having to dig in the ancestor path like this (get the last element of the path array):

```
getKey().getPathElement(c.element().getKey().getPathElementCount()-1).getId()
```

The second problem with timestamps: a little unelegant as well. I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation, how to format timestamp in Datastore or in BigQuery from the API point of view (data type, length of the field, its format, etc.). The solution that works now requires third party library ("joda"):

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;
```

And the below data translation. You have to remember that it is in milliseconds in one place and in microseconds in another. Another unnecessary confusion.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(props.get("timestamp").getTimestampMicrosecondsValu‌​e()/1000L);

row.set("timestamp", ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(dateTime));
```

Hope this helps others working with Dataflow and moving data from one place to another.

Comment: This is still the best way I could find to write a Millisecond value to BigQuery from Java.  Writing `java.util.Date` gives you seconds, and writing a `long` will give you Microseconds.